# Arrays in ASP.NET Core's XML Configuration Provider

Tags: xml, asp.net-core, .net-core

The ASP.NET Core (2.1) application I'm writing uses two configuration sources: JSON and XML (using framework's standard `AddJsonFile` and `AddXmlFile`. The XML settings have higher priority (e.g. should overwrite matching settings from the JSON file).

So far everything works fine, up until a point I had to create an array in XML file. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4):

Reference [Configuration in ASP.NET Core: Bind an array to a class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#bind-an-array-to-a-class)

> The `Bind` supports binding arrays to objects using array indices in configuration keys. Any array format that exposes a numeric key segment (`:0`, `:1`, … `:{n}`) is capable of array binding to a POCO class array.

I'll provide two examples of how to use arrays in XML config file

Using the following *`config.xml`*

```
<configuration>
  <tvshow>
    <metadata>
      <series>Dr. Who</series>
      <title>The Sun Makers</title>
      <airdate>11/26/1977</airdate>
      <episodes>4</episodes>
    </metadata>
    <actors name="0">Tom Baker</actors>
    <actors name="1">Louise Jameson</actors>
    <actors name="2">John Leeson</actors>
    <legal>(c)1977 BBC https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b006q2x0</legal>
  </tvshow>
</configuration>
```

The matching POCOs would look like

```cs
public class TvShow {
    public Metadata Metadata { get; set; }
    public string[] Actors { get; set; } //<-- TAKE NOTE
    public string Legal { get; set; }
}

public class Metadata {
    public string Series { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime AirDate { get; set; }
    public int Episodes { get; set; }
}
```

Given that `<actors>` elements' names, the resulting path would be

```
tvshow:actors:0
tvshow:actors:1
tvshow:actors:2
```

Which follows the convention stated in the documents

So in the following unit test it would pass as expected.

```cs
[TestClass]
public class Configuration_Should {
    [TestMethod]
    public void Bind_Xml_Arrays() {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddXmlFile("config.xml", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();

        var tvShow = config.GetSection("tvshow").Get<TvShow>();

        tvShow.Should().NotBeNull();

        tvShow.Actors.Should().HaveCount(3);
    }
}
```

In another example, suppose the `config.xml` was modified to the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration>
  <tvshow>
    <metadata>
      <series>Dr. Who</series>
      <title>The Sun Makers</title>
      <airdate>11/26/1977</airdate>
      <episodes>4</episodes>
    </metadata>
    <actors>
      <names name="0">Tom Baker</names>
      <names name="1">Louise Jameson</names>
      <names name="2">John Leeson</names>
    </actors>
    <legal>(c)1977 BBC https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b006q2x0</legal>
  </tvshow>
</configuration>
```

Would refactor the affected POCOs to

```cs
public class TvShow {
    public Metadata Metadata { get; set; }
    public Actors Actors { get; set; }
    public string Legal { get; set; }
}

//...Metadata omitted for brevity

public class Actors {
    public string[] Names { get; set; }
}
```

Again, following convention, the path for the array elements would need to look like

```
tvshow:actors:names:0
tvshow:actors:names:1
tvshow:actors:names:2
```

Which also behaves as expected when tested

```cs
[TestClass]
public class Configuration_Should {
    [TestMethod]
    public void Bind_Xml_Arrays() {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddXmlFile("config.xml", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();

        var tvShow = config.GetSection("tvshow").Get<TvShow>();

        tvShow.Should().NotBeNull();

        tvShow.Actors.Names.Should().HaveCount(3);
    }
}
```

This, along with the documentation should provide enough of a foundation for you to properly structure your XML configuration to bind to arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve array behavior by adding multiple tags with duplicated name of an array including `Name` attribute with element's "index in array". For instance the xml equivalent of this json

```
{
  "Values": [
    "value1",
    "value2",
    "value3"
  ],
  "Users": [
    {
      "Login": "log1",
      "Pass": "pass1"
    },
    {
      "Login": "log2",
      "Pass": "pass2"
    }
  ]
}
```

is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <Values name="0">value1</Values>
  <Values name="1">value2</Values>
  <Values name="2">value3</Values>
  <Users name="0">
    <Login>log1</Login>
    <Pass>pas1</Pass>
  </Users>
  <Users name="1">
    <Login>log2</Login>
    <Pass>pas2</Pass>
  </Users>
</configuration>
```

If you examine `Data` of respective `ConfigurationProvider`s that parsed *xml* and *json* configuration files

[image: configuration providers data]

you will see that *xml* provider contains extra entries with `name` suffix  contain values of `name` attributes but essentially both collections are equal.

And some simple tests confirm equality of both configurations

```
public class Configuration
{
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }

    public List<User> Users { get; set; }

}

public class User
{
    public string Login { get; set; }

    public string Pass { get; set; }
}

//this code returns the same result for every configuration
var config = new Configuration();
_configuration.Bind(config);

string value = _configuration.GetValue<string>("Values:0");
string login = _configuration.GetValue<string>("Users:0:Login");
```

**But it's not a full asnwer**

There is a serious drawback in this approach. Before posting this answer I tested how *xml* configuration works with third party libraries. And I tried to convert *json* config to *xml* for `Serilog`. This json

```
//..
"WriteTo": [
  { "Name": "Console" }
]
//..
```

converts to

```
//..
<WriteTo name="0">
  <Name>Console</Name>
</WriteTo>
//...
```

And at this point an exception arises

> System.FormatException: 'A duplicate key 'WriteTo:0:Name' was found. Line 11, position 11.'

Remember that extra entries from xml `ConfigurationProvider`? Well, now everything crashes because of them. So the conclusion is you cannot convert *json* array to *xml* if its objects contain `Name` key.

**Some good news**

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/pull/862) that allows to use tags with duplicated names without `Name` attribute. This should fix that drawback. Also there is [code](https://github.com/amoerie/configuration.xml) for `XmlConfigurationProvider` from the same guy that you can already use in your project.

Comment: @MichałDudak Well, that's really unfortunate. As I mentioned in my answer consider using custom `ConfigurationProvider` from github or you can roll your own implementation if you desperately need xml configuration to be used.